# Why ntfsusermap can't map all ntfs partition in my os?

Tags: linux, partitioning, mount, ntfs

`sda4` and `sda5` are all `ntfs` partition.

```
sudo blkid |grep ntfs
/dev/sda4: UUID="0042E54842E54350" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="9f1dac15-dcb3-11ea-8492-d66553422507"
/dev/sda5: UUID="C0FC6E55FC6E462E" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="1bb1cb5a-4418-41ce-8210-827072f17a47"
```

I can mount `/dev/sda4`.

```
sudo ntfsusermap /dev/sda4
```

[image]

Now start to mount `/dev/sda5`:

```
sudo ntfsusermap /dev/sda5
```

The output info:

```
This tool will help you to build a mapping of Windows users
to Linux users.
Be prepared to give Linux user id (uid) and group id (gid)
for owners of files which will be selected.
"/dev/sda5" opened

* Scanning "/dev/sda5" (two levels)
* Search for "Documents and Settings" and "Users"
* Search for other directories /
"/dev/sda5" closed
```

It can't pop up  `User` and `Group` to let me type in,why `ntfsusermap` can't  map all ntfs partition  in my os?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Command [`ntfsusermap`](https://manpages.debian.org/buster/ntfs-3g/ntfsusermap.8.en.html) is for "Building a User Mapping File", not for mounting.

The message you get probably means that there were no users found in `/dev/sda5` to build such mapping file (although a message `You have defined no user, no mapping can be built` might be expected).

If you only want to get access to `/dev/sda5` files, you may want to simply `mount` that partition.
Create a mount point, and then mount the partition

```
mkdir /mnt/win2
sudo mount -t ntfs /dev/sda5 /mnt/win2
```

or for a more flexible operation

```
mkdir /mnt/win2
sudo mount -t ntfs-3g -o permissions /dev/sda5 /mnt/win2
```

This is for a one time mounting.
You may configure your system to know the mount parameters, and to mount on boot.

Notes:

1. It can help if you post the output of [`fdisk`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/fdisk.8.html): `sudo fdisk -l`.
2. Which partitions are `sda4` and `sda5` when you boot Windows? Can you post the output of `dir` on the respective root directories?
3. See detailed examples for `ntfsusermap` [here](https://jp-andre.pagesperso-orange.fr/ntfsusermap.html).

Answer (score 0):

Please give more information about the differences between sda5 and sda4.

I note that if sda5 does not contain a Windows installation, then what is
happening is entirely normal.

From
[ntfsusermap man](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/cosmic/man8/ntfsusermap.8.html):

> **ntfsusermap** `windows-system-device` [`other-ntfs-device`...]
>
> Where `windows-system-device` is the device containing the Windows
> system whose users are to be mapped to current Linux system.
>
> And `other-ntfs-device` is another device containing files which are to be
> accessed both  by the Windows mentioned above and current Linux system.

If sda5 does not contain a Windows installation, the command should in this case
be:

```
sudo ntfsusermap /dev/sda4 /dev/sda5
```